# oozie - How to refer Hadoop name-node and job-tracker given in oozie server config .xml to job.properties file for workflow reference

Tags: configuration, oozie

I have specified the hadoop name node and job tracker as given in the oozie documentation:

```
<property>
        <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.jobTracker.whitelist</name>
        <value> </value>
        <description>
           job tracker for Oozie service.
        </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.nameNode.whitelist</name>
        <value> </value>
        <description>
            name node for Oozie service.
        </description>
    </property>
...
```

Now how can I refer this value in my job.properties file? Giving the above property name is not working as the workflow is not initializing

Comment: These properties are labeled `whitelist`, which implies that _(a)_ they expect a **list** of addresses and _(b)_ they are used by Oozie **server** to accept/reject the actual addresses indicated in each workflow. I wonder what kind of documentation you have been reading. Google for a tutorial instead -- for instance, the _"hooked on Hadoop"_ series...

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link. the solution I am looking for is to avoid putting name node and job tracker URLs in every job.property file. I would like to define the name node and job tracker urls at one place at oozie server level and refer it in job.properties and workflow.xml

Comment: Well, that's exactly what Oozie was *not* expected to do. It was designed at Yahoo! as a *multi-cluster* scheduler service, that's why there is no default conf... Anyway, note that if you run YARN with high availability, you can put a dummy value for `jobTracker` because Oozie will fall back to its `yarn-site.xml` rules.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It sounds good feature.  My installation is running on single cluster as part of Hadoop distribution.  Using  job.properties file for specifying the job-tracker and name-node seems light  overhead to maintain this multi-cluster feature.